# spring-boot w/ embedded tomcat doesn't dispatch requests to controller

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have an application using spring-boot and an embedded Tomcat container.

As far as I can tell, my code is the same as the spring-boot [sample project](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat). However, when I run my test, I get a 404 instead of a 200 (in the case where I try to post instead of get I receive a 405, which is consistent with Tomcat being incorrectly setup):

```
Failed tests:
UserControllerTest.testMethod:45 Status expected:<200> but was:<404>
```

My Java-based configuration (some configuration classes omitted):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import({ ServiceConfig.class, DefaultRepositoryConfig.class })
public class ApplicationConfig {

    private static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(ApplicationConfig.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class);
    }

    @Bean
    protected ServletContextListener listener() {
        return new ServletContextListener() {
            @Override
            public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
                logger.info("ServletContext initialized");
            }

            @Override
            public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
                logger.info("ServletContext destroyed");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

UserController.java:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> testMethod() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Success!", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

UserControllerTest.java:

```
RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ApplicationConfig.class})
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Is there something basic I'm missing? I'm not providing my own Mvc configuration, and I haven't touched the Spring MVC DispatcherServlet, so I assume spring-boot will configure Tomcat automatically.

Comment: Your question does not detail what your problem is exactly. I see you mention `405` instead of `404`. But your quoted result shows something else. Please elaborate on what the problem is, what are the conditions involved and the expected result

Comment: I have edited my question to be more clear.

Essentially, I expect my JUnit testMethod() to hit UserController.testMethod(). The result should be a 200 and a successful compilation.

Comment: The 405 is correct and expected isn't it? Not sure about the 404, but you should see your mapping being registered in logs when you start the context (maybe in DEBUG). It normally gives you a full report on the mapping.

Comment: For information: it would help if you use `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` instead of `@ContextConfiguration` in a Spring Boot app (ensures you get all the same features starting up the application context). Shouldn't make any difference here from what we can see, and a simple application in the same form works for me, so I suspect you are hiding something important. If you can post the whole project that would help.

Comment: I hadn't seen @SpringApplicationConfiguration yet, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 16):

It turns out the issue was the component scanning configuration. Even though the `@ComponentScan` annotation was used, the controller was under a separate package, so Spring never included it in the dispatcher.

Adding `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.controller"))` solved my issue.

Comment: thanks for this helpful answer. Hope spring boot document it :)