# ERROR 1045 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

Im doing a task to my university and I want to use Spring Boot. Im not using database, just a fake data class.

When I try to access "/" or my index page I got the following ERROR:

**2015-10-25 14:10:41.113 ERROR 1045 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false**

[That is my file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85Njr.png)

My main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);


 }
}
```

My controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

@Value("${application.message:Hello World}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping(value="/")
public String index(Map<String, Object> model){

    model.put("message", message);
    return "index";
}

}
```

My index.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www. springframework .org/tags"%>
<html>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    Message: ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

My POM

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>alocation-spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>alocation-spring</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>alocation-spring Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>alocation-spring</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                <logger name="org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter">
                    <level value="OFF" />
                </logger>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you set the prefix and sufix for the jsp files in any config/properties file? Please try adding `spring.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/` and `spring.view.suffix=.jsp` to `src/main/resource/application.properties` file..

Comment: I had already put this setting, and it didnt work. :(

Comment: can you try remove the `@SpringBootApplication` and add these three `@Configuration`  
`@EnableAutoConfiguration`  
`@ComponentScan`.. May be the controller class is not picked up by spring, you can verify this by checking the startup logs. If the class is detected, you can see logs saying that the mappings have been registered.

Comment: @redflar3 , I did what you told and I see that: 2015-10-25 15:44:32.942  INFO 1370 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/]}" onto public java.lang.String br.ufrgs.inf.alocation.controller.IndexController.index(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>)

Comment: When I use @SpringBootApplication I see the same mapping.

Comment: Using `@SpringBootApplication` is exactly the same as using the 3 annotations, so that won't change anything. There is an additional space in your jsp (in the tag declaration) which might break the JSP. Next to that I would strongly suggest NOT to use JSP but use something like Thymeleaf instead.

Comment: Thank you , I will see about Thymeleaf. About my problem, I found solution: If Im not using XML to set my configs, I must use @RestController .

Comment: @Deinum ofcourse if you look inside you will see these 3 annotations, but the way Spring Boot uses it, these are some limitations based on package. As per my experience with spring boot, if the component is in a different package than the main class, you need to somehow explicitly ask boot to scan for the other packages. Alternative to that is to breakdown the annotation into those three, that removed the need to specify the packages. you can see may related qns in SO. So, per my experience, those two are not the same. Pls correct me if I am wrong.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547117